# Conical Related Rates

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

Sand falls from a conveyor belt at a rate of 11 $\frac{\text{m}^3}{\text{min}}$ onto the top of a conical pile. The height of the pile is always three-eights of the diameter of the base. Give the rate at which the height changing when the pile is $4 \text{ m}$ high.

$$
\\ \begin{align*}
\\ \frac{dV}{dt} &= 11 \frac{\text{m}^3}{\text{min}}
\\ V &= \frac{1}{3} \pi r^2 h
\\ h &= \frac{3}{8}D
\\ \frac{8}{3}h &= D
\\ r &= \frac{1}{2}D
\\ r &= \frac{4}{3}h
\\ V &= \frac{\pi}{3}{(\frac{4}{3}h)}^2 h
\\ V &= \frac{16 \pi}{27}h^3
\\ \frac{27}{16 \pi}V &= h^3
\\ \frac{d}{dt} \left[ \frac{27}{16 \pi}V \right] &= \frac{d}{dt} \left[ h^3 \right]
\\ \frac{27}{16 \pi} \cdot \frac{dV}{dt} &= 3h^2 \frac{dh}{dt}
\\ \frac{9}{16 \pi h^2} \cdot \frac{dV}{dt} &= \frac{dh}{dt}
\\ \frac{99}{256 \pi} \frac{\text{m}}{\text{min}} &= \frac{dh}{dt} \approx 0.12 \frac{\text{m}}{\text{min}}
\end{align*}
$$

By this, I find the height to be changing at a rate of $\frac{dh}{dt} \approx 0.12 \frac{\text{m}}{\text{min}}$.

Verify/dispute?

Comment: Your solution is fine.

Comment: I see my error. It's desired in $\frac{cm}{min}$.

Comment: @BRICS-Fan I didn't convert to centimetres. Everything else is fine, though.